# Spring Boot runnable jar can't load terracotta

Tags: spring, spring-boot, classloader, terracotta, urlclassloader

I've been pulling my hair out all day on this one. I finally found a workaround but I really want to know why it's happening.

I have a spring boot app with a bunch of dependencies (activemq, hibernate, terracotta, etc) which runs perfectly from inside Eclipse, and I build it with the default spring boot maven plugin:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

By typing:

```
mvn clean package
```

It builds a runnable uberjar and when I run it, I can see that it connects to ActiveMQ, then it connects to the database using Hibernate, then when it tries to connect to Terracotta caches I get:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataCacheRegistry' defined in class path resource [com/algomi/ase/terracotta/DataCacheRegistryConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.algomi.infra.server.datacache.DataCacheRegistry]: Factory method 'dataCacheRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create module because of error with DataCache configuration for module: AseCalculatorRestService
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1023) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.algomi.infra.server.datacache.DataCacheRegistry]: Factory method 'dataCacheRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create module because of error with DataCache configuration for module: AseCalculatorRestService
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        ... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create module because of error with DataCache configuration for module: AseCalculatorRestService
        at com.algomi.infra.server.datacache.DatacacheFactory.buildDataCache(DatacacheFactory.java:72) ~[infra-server-common-1.2.7.jar!/:1.2.7]
        at com.algomi.infra.server.datacache.DatacacheFactory.buildDataCaches(DatacacheFactory.java:32) ~[infra-server-common-1.2.7.jar!/:1.2.7]
        at com.algomi.ase.terracotta.DataCacheRegistryConfig.dataCacheRegistry(DataCacheRegistryConfig.java:23) ~[classes!/:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.algomi.ase.terracotta.DataCacheRegistryConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$780857d9.CGLIB$dataCacheRegistry$0(<generated>) ~[classes!/:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.algomi.ase.terracotta.DataCacheRegistryConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$780857d9$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$35534a1e.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes!/:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at com.algomi.ase.terracotta.DataCacheRegistryConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$780857d9.dataCacheRegistry(<generated>) ~[classes!/:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at com.algomi.infra.server.datacache.DatacacheFactory.buildDataCache(DatacacheFactory.java:68) ~[infra-server-common-1.2.7.jar!/:1.2.7]
        ... 53 common frames omitted
Caused by: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Unable to load class net.sf.ehcache.terracotta.StandaloneTerracottaClusteredInstanceFactory. Initial cause was null
        at net.sf.ehcache.util.ClassLoaderUtil.createNewInstance(ClassLoaderUtil.java:109) ~[ehcache-core-2.6.11.jar!/:na]
        at net.sf.ehcache.terracotta.TerracottaClusteredInstanceHelper.newClusteredInstanceFactory(TerracottaClusteredInstanceHelper.java:176) ~[ehcache-core-2.6.11.jar!/:na]
        at net.sf.ehcache.terracotta.TerracottaClient.createNewClusteredInstanceFactory(TerracottaClient.java:186) ~[ehcache-core-2.6.11.jar!/:na]
        at net.sf.ehcache.terracotta.TerracottaClient.createClusteredInstanceFactory(TerracottaClient.java:138) ~[ehcache-core-2.6.11.jar!/:na]
        at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.doInit(CacheManager.java:432) ~[ehcache-core-2.6.11.jar!/:na]
        at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:377) ~[ehcache-core-2.6.11.jar!/:na]
        at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.<init>(CacheManager.java:317) ~[ehcache-core-2.6.11.jar!/:na]
        at com.capxd.infra.common.model.EhcacheManager.getCacheManager(EhcacheManager.java:42) ~[messaging-2.1.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.capxd.infra.common.model.EhcacheManager.getBackingCache(EhcacheManager.java:27) ~[messaging-2.1.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.capxd.infra.common.model.EhcacheDataCache.getBackingCache(EhcacheDataCache.java:63) ~[messaging-2.1.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.capxd.infra.common.model.EhcacheDataCache.<init>(EhcacheDataCache.java:43) ~[messaging-2.1.1.jar!/:na]
        ... 58 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
        at net.sf.ehcache.terracotta.StandaloneTerracottaClusteredInstanceFactory.<init>(StandaloneTerracottaClusteredInstanceFactory.java:37) ~[ehcache-terracotta-2.6.11.jar!/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at net.sf.ehcache.util.ClassLoaderUtil.createNewInstance(ClassLoaderUtil.java:92) ~[ehcache-core-2.6.11.jar!/:na]
        ... 68 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
        at com.terracotta.express.ClientFactoryImpl.<init>(ClientFactoryImpl.java:93) ~[terracotta-toolkit-1.6-runtime-5.10.0.jar!/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at org.terracotta.express.Util.getImplInstance(Util.java:11) ~[terracotta-toolkit-1.6-runtime-5.10.0.jar!/:na]
        at org.terracotta.express.ClientFactory.<clinit>(ClientFactory.java:14) ~[terracotta-toolkit-1.6-runtime-5.10.0.jar!/:na]
        ... 74 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
        at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1931) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarURLConnection.extractFullSpec(JarURLConnection.java:257) ~[ase-calculator-rest-service-0.0.2-20161110.103558-5.jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarURLConnection.get(JarURLConnection.java:228) ~[ase-calculator-rest-service-0.0.2-20161110.103558-5.jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:88) ~[ase-calculator-rest-service-0.0.2-20161110.103558-5.jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:972) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1038) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at com.terracotta.express.ClientFactoryImpl.handleJarUrl(ClientFactoryImpl.java:102) ~[terracotta-toolkit-1.6-runtime-5.10.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.terracotta.express.ClientFactoryImpl.<init>(ClientFactoryImpl.java:84) ~[terracotta-toolkit-1.6-runtime-5.10.0.jar!/:na]
        ... 81 common frames omitted
```

I downloaded all the source code for terracotta, then for spring loader, and eventually found that the problem is in the method:

```
private static String extractFullSpec(URL url, String pathFromRoot) {
    String file = url.getFile();
    int separatorIndex = file.indexOf(SEPARATOR);
    if (separatorIndex < 0) {
        return "";
    }
    int specIndex = separatorIndex + SEPARATOR.length() + pathFromRoot.length();
    return file.substring(specIndex);
}
```

This method is in `org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarURLConnection` in `spring-boot-loader-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar`. The problem seems to be in the incoming parameter `url`. The following jars (and as far as I can make out every other jar) loads with no problem:

```
file:/C:/Dev/Repos/state-engine/calculator-rest-service/target/calculator-rest-service-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-validation-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar!/
file:/C:/Dev/Repos/state-engine/calculator-rest-service/target/calculator-rest-service-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/evo-inflector-1.2.1.jar!/
file:/C:/Dev/Repos/state-engine/calculator-rest-service/target/calculator-rest-service-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/hibernate-c3p0-3.6.10.Final.jar!/
```

But then the terracotta one fails:

```
file:/C:/Dev/Repos/state-engine/calculator-rest-service/target/calculator-rest-service-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/terracotta-toolkit-1.6-runtime-5.10.0.jar!
```

The `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` happens because there is an assumption in the method, as far as I can make out, that all URLs will end with "!/" but the URL for terracotta is missing the trailing '/'.

The workaround was to add the following in my pom to make the Launcher into a PropertiesLauncher:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <layout>ZIP</layout>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And put my terracotta jar in a separate libs folder and run my jar with `java -Dloader.path=C:/temp/libs/lib -jar xxx`.

This is annoying though to have to have my terracotta jar in a separate libs folder when every other jar loads perfectly fine from inside my uberjar.

Any ideas how I get the uberjar to work with terracotta inside it and using the JarLauncher istead of PropertiesLauncher???